# How to create uparrow downarrow using simple css

Tags: css

Please find this css class to create simple uparrow downarrow left arrow and right arrow.

```
<html>
<style>
.left {border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid red;
    border-top: 9px solid transparent;
    float: left;}
.right {border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
    border-left: 10px solid red;
    border-top: 9px solid transparent;
    float: left;}
.top{ border-color: black transparent transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 11px 7px 10px;
    float: left;}
.bottom {border-color: transparent transparent black !important;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 27px 19px 25px;
    float: right;}  
</style>    
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
<div class="top"></div>
<div class="bottom"></div>
</html>
```

Class left means Leftward arrow.,
Any one please suggest me the better way of creating arrows using simple css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

css tricks may be browser/version limited.

You can also get icon images here:
http://www.iconarchive.com/search?q=arrow+up

Small ones here:
http://p.yusukekamiyamane.com/icons/search/fugue/#keyword=arrow

Answer (score 3):

The solution you have presented in your question **is** the best one if you care about IE7 compatibility.

Yes, there are other ways to achieve the same thing.

For example, *if you drop IE7 support*, then you could apply these same styles to [**`:before`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/%3abefore)/ [**`:after`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/%3aafter) pseudo-elements and avoid cluttering your HTML.

You also have the option of using [gradients](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/linear-gradient) to create triangles - [**example**](http://dabblet.com/gist/2705739). However, this is one solution that *won't even work in IE9, which is the current IE version*.

Comment: Please provide  worked example which uses :before and :after psdo-Classes

Answer (score 0):

A css arrow can be created using this style. you need to set the width and height of the arrow.

```
div.left {
    z-index: 2000;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border-top: 2px solid #ddd;
    border-left: 2px solid rgba(150,150,150,0.4);
    text-indent: -90000px;
    cursor: pointer;

    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

also if you need a easier way then you can always switch to use images

Comment: for ie7 and older its better you switch to images, working with them are like banging your head