# Displaying up/down arrows in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I have created table with sorter in angular js.
 But I am unable to display up/down arrows to my code.What did I do wrong?

```js
 var app=angular.module("myModule",[])

     .controller("myController",function($scope){

var employees=[
{name:"suha",dob:new Date("november,20,1995"),gender:"female",salary:"57300.00"},
{name:"Yashu",dob:new Date("august,25,1997"),gender:"female",salary:"47653.0000"},
{name:"sneha",dob:new Date("july,30,1999"),gender:"female",salary:"43300.00"}
];
$scope.employees=employees;
$scope.sortColumn="name";
$scope.reverseSort=false;

$scope.sortData=function(column){
    $scope.reverseSort=($scope.sortColumn==column)? !$scope.reverseSort : false;
    $scope.sortColumn=column;
}
$scope.getSortClass=function(column){
    if($scope.sortColumn==column){
        return $scope.reverseSort ? 'arrow-down' : 'arrow-up';
    }

    return '';
}

});
```

```css
table,tr,td{
    border:1px solid;
    padding:10px;
}
.arrow-up,.arrow-down{
    width:0;
    height:0;
    border-right: 5px transparent;
    border-left: 5px transparent;
    border-bottom-color: 10px solid black;
    display: inline-block;

}
```

Complete code: https://jsfiddle.net/4vy9m3h1/

Comment: you are getting Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined error ?

Comment: Yah.In my local am getting correct output only arrows are not displaying.But here am getting `Uncaught Reference error` I don't know why.should I add any reference?

Comment: make sure your code is working properly so that I can help you change the fiddle also

Comment: @BOSS Sorry I din't get you.Can you please tell me,Should I add any reference? please check my fiddle .

Comment: your fiddle code is also giving some error please fix that then .. I can help you :) .. see the fiddle console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `ng-class` to `th` like below

```
<th ng-click="sortData('name')" ng-class="getSortClass('name')">
  Name
</th>
```

See the working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gangadharjannu/0165oup7/)

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gangadharjannu/1xkkucpv/) with arrow icons:

Comment: Thank you so much.Fiddle is working good.Please check arrows are not displaying

Comment: @user7397787 that is the issue with css. Refere http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11712011/how-to-create-uparrow-downarrow-using-simple-css

Comment: @user7397787 Check the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gangadharjannu/1xkkucpv/)

Comment: Great.Thank you so much:-) :-) :-)

Answer (score 1):

The problem actually lies on your CSS. This should work:

```
table,tr,td{
    border:1px solid;
    padding:10px;
}

.arrow-up{
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
}

.arrow-down{
    width:0;
    height: 0;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

You've entered a wrong property/value, i.e. using shorthand within this property `border-bottom-color`.